# Remove 1 Item from List Collection using LinQ C#

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, visual-studio

I have the next List:

```
1
5
2
1
2
9
1
```

In this case I have number 1 repeated three times.
I need to create an expression using LinQ in which the number you wish to delete specified Only One Time:

Example:

```
RemoveItem(1), Result:
    1
    5
    2
    1
    2
    9
```

The function containing the linq only remove 1 item and not all.

I've heard of .RemoveAll, but I removed all duplicates and I only need to remove one.

Comment: How will you know which `1` to remove?

Comment: No matter whatever it may be removed.

Comment: How about using `RemoveAt` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for `First` item matching your criteria and remove it like:

```
List<int> yourList = new List<int> { 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 9, 1 };
yourList.Remove(yourList.FirstOrDefault(r=> r == 1));
```

Or simply:

```
yourList.Remove(1);
```

since [`List<T>.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) will remove the first occurrence of specified object.

*(Using `FirstOrDefault` would be useful if you are dealing with List of reference types (class objects))*

This will remove the the first item found matching the criteria so after first remove you will be left with `5, 2, 1, 2, 9, 1` in your list.

If you want to remove the item from end of the list then use `RemoveAt` like:

```
yourList.RemoveAt(yourList.LastIndexOf(1));
```